# How to extend or modify Codeigniter calendar to handle multi-day events and multiple events per day

Tags: php, codeigniter, calendar

I'd hate to reinvent the wheel on this one if it's out there somewhere, but has anyone extended or modified the codigniter calendar to handle multi-day events and multiple events per day or is it there a module available somewhere?

Comment: It seems that this is what you need : http://sharpwebsolutions.com/2011/multiple-events-per-day-on-codeigniter-calenda/

Comment: These are good answers, but is there 1 solution that allows both multi-day events and multiple events per day?

Comment: Mine does. I'm using it in my application right now.

Comment: @lrussell810 I'm working on this today. I'll let you know if it works or not.

Comment: Awesome. I hope that you find what you're looking for in all these answers. Keep in mind too that you can even set up Associative Arrays that work splendidly with the `Calendar.php` modification mentioned in my answer. I've also included more code than that which was modified to help you find it easier in the `Calendar.php` file. Good luck with everything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily modified in the file `system/libraries/Calendar.php` with the following addition of code. I know that editing any system file is considered taboo, but this helped me out in my application a ton. Take note of the `foreach()` loop in the commented section that says `//If more than one event on the same day.` This is the code that needs to be added to the Calendar.php library file. This resource can be futher elaborated on at the following link.

```
http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/196998/
```

Calendar.php modified code:

```
if (isset($data[$day]))
                    {
                        // Cells with content
                        $temp = ($is_current_month == TRUE AND $day == $cur_day) ? $this->temp['cal_cell_content_today'] : $this->temp['cal_cell_content'];

                        // If more than one event on the same day
                        if (is_array($data[$day]))
                        {
                          $several_events = '';
                          foreach ($data[$day] as $key => $value)
                          {
                            $several_events .= '<li id="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</li>';
                          }
                          $out .= str_replace('{day}', $day, str_replace('{content}', $several_events, $temp));
                        }

                        // One event per day
                        else
                        {
                          $out .= str_replace('{day}', $day, str_replace('{content}', $data[$day], $temp));
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Cells with no content
                        $temp = ($is_current_month == TRUE AND $day == $cur_day) ? $this->temp['cal_cell_no_content_today'] : $this->temp['cal_cell_no_content'];
                        $out .= str_replace('{day}', $day, $temp);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // Blank cells
                    $out .= $this->temp['cal_cell_blank'];
                }
```

Keep in mind that I've shown more than just the edited code above to help you locate it within `Calendar.php`. I hope this helps!

Comment: How should the multi-day events be stored in the db? If i have a 3 day long event, should I have 3 records in the db, with consecutive dates and the same content?

Comment: Or should I have 1 record with a start date column and an end date column.

Comment: You should have three records within the database, with consecutive dates, and the same content. Here's why: CodeIgniter generates the Calendar class events at `<li>`s, and even if the event is three days long, it's most likely going to have a start time and stop time for each day; allowing them to separate in the database easily. This is how other databases function with this type of situation as well. If you need help crafting the database to these specifications, I'd check out MySQLWorkbench to play around with ideas. It's wonderful, and free! http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/

Comment: You're code helped me out a ton. Got me on the right track. I appreciate your help.

Comment: You don't need to edit system files. Just extend the Calendar library by creating MY_Calendar.php in application/libraries/.

Answer (score 3):

Multiple events for one day is actually very easy. It just takes changing the calendar template and here is an example from some of my code.

```
public function print_calendar($year = 0, $month = 0)
{
    $prefs = array (
        'show_next_prev'  => FALSE,
        'next_prev_url'   => site_url('events/print_calendar'),
        'day_type'        => 'long',
        'template'        => '
            {heading_row_start}{/heading_row_start}
            {heading_previous_cell}{/heading_previous_cell}
            {heading_title_cell}<h1>{heading}</h1>{/heading_title_cell}
            {heading_next_cell}{/heading_next_cell}
            {heading_row_end}{/heading_row_end}

            {table_open}<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">{/table_open}

            {week_row_start}<tr>{/week_row_start}
            {week_day_cell}<th bgcolor="#999999">{week_day}</th>{/week_day_cell}
            {week_row_end}</tr>{/week_row_end}

            {cal_row_start}<tr>{/cal_row_start}
            {cal_cell_start}<td background="'.s3_path('images/print_cal_cell.jpg').'">{/cal_cell_start}

            {cal_cell_content}<span class="cal_day">{day}</span>{content}{/cal_cell_content}
            {cal_cell_content_today}<span class="cal_day">{day}</span>{/cal_cell_content_today}

            {cal_cell_no_content}<span class="cal_day">{day}</span>{/cal_cell_no_content}
            {cal_cell_no_content_today}<span class="cal_day">{day}</span>{/cal_cell_no_content_today}

            {cal_cell_blank}&nbsp;{/cal_cell_blank}

            {cal_cell_end}</td>{/cal_cell_end}
            {cal_row_end}</tr>{/cal_row_end}

            {table_close}</table>{/table_close}
        '
    );

    $this->load->library('calendar', $prefs);

    $year = ($year == 0) ? date('Y') : $year;
    $month = ($month == 0) ? date('n') : $month;
    $start = strtotime('1-'.$month.'-'.$year);

    $events = $this->events_model->get_by_date($start, strtotime('+1 month', $start));
    $this->template->set_layout('');

    if ($events)
    {
        foreach ($events as $key => $event)
        {
            $day = date('j', $event['showing_start_time']);
            $vars[$day] = $this->template->build('events/calendar/cal_item', $event, TRUE);
        }
    }

    $vars['content'] = $this->calendar->generate($year, $month, $vars);
    $this->load->view('calendar/cal_layout', $vars);
}
```

Hopefully that code is clear and can give you a good starting point. What I normally do if they span multiple days just include the item on each day.

Comment: Off topic, why is template inside function?

Comment: The calendar template needs to be passed when you load the library and this was an easy way to show it in the post.

Comment: can I have date inside {cal_cell_blank} instead of blank?